# Column editing in Vim

Tags: vim

Say I'm writing some repetitive code like:

```
add(x+1) 
add(x+2)
add(x+3)
add(x+4)
```

How can I use vim's column editing to make say 1000 lines of this code with the same pattern?

Comment: Or you could just write your code in loops instead.

Comment: What if she is doing loop unfolding? :P

Comment: yeah the whole point was to be doing loop unfolding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### use macro

type one line: `add(x+1)`, then type in normal mode:

```
qqYp<ctrl-a>q
```

to record one macro. Now you can just `999@q` to have 1000 lines in this pattern.

### use `g<c-a>`

type one line: `add(x+1)`, then type in normal mode:

```
Y999p
```

Now you have 1000 duplicated lines with `+1)`, then:

```
2G<ctrl-v>}g<ctrl-a>
```

You got it.

Comment: @pfnuesel it is not ex cmd. you just press the keystrokes in normal mode

Comment: @pfnuesel I cannot see what you have done, but what you described should not happen. what `Y99p` does just yank your current line and paste 99 times.